# Qualtrics - auto advance when maximum characters allowed entered

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm trying to find out how I can get my questions to auto advance to the next when the maximum characters allowed have been met?

I am computerising the CatBat task.
The task consists of a short written story, participants have to fill in these missing letters. the missing letter in the first part of the story is C, and in the second part is B.

I am using a 'text entry' question type with a maximum character allowed of 1.

Basically I don't want my participants to have the time to think about it/change their answer, therefore why I'd like to set up an auto advance as soon as they have answered.

Anyone can help?

thank you!

Comment: Hi Laura. Welcome to SO. Can you add your current code (see [mcve]) to your question to make it easier to understand your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)